# xlsxwriter modifying worksheet font

Tags: xlsxwriter

I need assistance modifying the font and size of excel spreadsheet from default to 'Arial' 9.  I'm able to modify the header row, but unable to get the body of the spreadsheet to do the same.  I'm using xlsxwriter, I'm sure it's something simple just not that familiar with xlsxwriter.   See code below, any assistance greatly appreciated.

```py
Pipeline_details.to_excel(writer1, 
                          sheet_name ='Pipeline_Details',
                          startrow=1,
                          startcol=0,
                          header=False,
                          index=False)

workbook = writer1.book
worksheet = writer1.sheets['Pipeline Details']
(max_row, max_col) = Pipeline_details.shape
worksheet.autofilter(0,0,max_row, max_col - 1)
worksheer.hide_gridlines(2)

header_format = workbook_add.format({
    'font_name': 'Arial',
    'font_size': 9,
    'bold': False,
    'text_wrap': True})

for col_num, value in enumerate(Pipeline_details.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)

cell_format = workbook.add_format({'font_name': 'Arial', 'font_size': 9})

writer1.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [formatting while using pandas with xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-output) state the following:

> XlsxWriter and Pandas provide very little support for formatting the output data from a dataframe apart from default formatting such as the header and index cells and any cells that contain dates or datetimes. In addition it isn’t possible to format any cells that already have a default format applied.

> If you require very controlled formatting of the dataframe output then you would probably be better off using Xlsxwriter directly with raw data taken from Pandas.

That being said

> It is possible to format any other, non date/datetime column data using set_column()

For an example using A notation, you'd execute this after writing your data to the worksheet:

```
worksheet.set_column('A:Z', None, format)
```

I'd try that first to see if you get anywhere with it. Otherwise I'd suggest writing your rows yourself and adding your format that way.